# Help with derivative inside a summation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

I have $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2q^kp=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k[kq^{k-1}]qp=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k[\frac{d}{dq}(q^k)]qp$.

How can I go about pulling this $\frac{d}{dq}$ outside of the sum?

Comment: You mean $\frac{d}{dq}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that typo.

Comment: It's not clear if this sum is convergent or not which makes operations like that ill-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need the series to converge and $p$ is not a function of $q$ as julian said.

If it converges,then:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2q^kp=\frac {1}{k+1}\cdot \frac {d}{dq} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 q^{k+1}p$

Comment: @julianfernandez ,better? Please don't use exclamation marks with this attitude.

Comment: it was a joke, please do not take it bad

Comment: assuming p is not a function of q

Comment: @julianfernandez,correct:)