# Is calculating the summation of derivatives "mathematically sound"?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

I have just discovered that if you take the following series: $$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdot \cdot \cdot = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n$$ and replace each term in the series with the derivative of them, you'll get: $$1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4$$ Which I think could simplify to this: $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac {d}{dx}x^n$$ The question about this is: Is it [mathematically] sound to compute a summation of derivatives (or differentials)? I'm asking this because it looks like it is sound in this case because we are adding up all the derivatives of $x^n$ until $x = \infty$. So, is it sound to compute sums of derivatives?

### Reminders about Question

I have seen a question related to this: [infinite summation of derivatives of a  convergent function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526198/infinite-summation-of-derivatives-of-a-convergent-function), but it didn't get me to where I am aiming for. I have also seen [Calculus Summations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280357/calculus-summations) and [Help with derivative inside a summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967311/help-with-derivative-inside-a-summation), but they don't answer my question.

Comment: So what are you aiming for?

Comment: This may help:http://www.phengkimving.com/calc_of_one_real_var/15_rep_of_func_by_pow_series/15_02_der_and_intgrl_of_pow_series.htm

Comment: What I am aiming for, @MhenniBenghorbal, is if it is sound to compute sums of derivatives.

Comment: The following may be useful. If a power series $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$ has radius of convergence $R$, then whenever $|x|\lt R$ we can freely differentiate term by term.

Comment: Sorry, @NoChance, your resource didn't help me. It isn't even related to the question.

Comment: There is no apparent problem in computing the sum of derivatives. In your example, the infinite sum converges only if $|x|\leq 1$. So if you want any real number to be equal to the infinite sum, then you must consider the radius of convergence, otherwise your query does not matter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This sort of thing usually comes up in the context of trying to interchange the derivative with the sum: that is, you would like to have

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f'_n(x)$$

by analogy with the case of finite summation. This interchange can sometimes fail. The most basic criterion that I have heard of is one of the "advanced calculus criteria" (so called because it is taught in undergraduate real analysis and has no famous name). It requires that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f'_n(x)$ converges uniformly in $x$ (over the domain on which you have the equality). Milder criteria exist; for instance there is a variant based on the dominated convergence theorem from measure theory.

I'm not sure if this answers your question because I'm not sure what "sound" means in this context.

Comment: In this context, sound means valid.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue But valid to do what? To write down the new sum, or to obtain the new sum by differentiating the original sum, or what?

Comment: What I mean is valid in terms of computing the derivative of $x^n$ for every $n$ that the summation uses up until $\infty$ and "add the derivatives up".

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue You can certainly compute the derivatives themselves and sum them. The sum might not be convergent, even if the original sum was convergent (for instance when $f_n(x)=\sin(n^2x)/n^2$), but you can certainly write it down. The question is mostly interesting when you ask about the interchange.

Comment: Okay, that answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Also, @Ian (and I apologize for responding 3 months late), I actually asked a follow-up question about the interchange between the summation and derivative here: [Is $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n \right) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\frac{d}{dx} x^n)$ true?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811754/is-fracddx-left-sum-n-0-infty-xn-right-sum-n-0-infty-left?lq=1)

Answer (score 20):

Notice that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^N \left( \frac {\sin((n+1)x)}{n+1} - \frac{\sin(nx)} n \right) = \frac{\sin((N+1)x)}{N+1} - \frac{\sin(2x)} 2 \longrightarrow \frac{-\sin(2x)} 2 \text{ as } N\to\infty
$$
and so
$$
\frac d {dx} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \frac {\sin((n+1)x)}{n+1} - \frac{\sin(nx)} n \right) = \frac d {dx} \frac{-\sin(2x)} 2 = -\cos(2x).
$$
But
\begin{align}
& \sum_{n=2}^N \frac d {dx} \left( \frac {\sin((n+1)x)}{n+1} - \frac{\sin(nx)} n \right) \\[8pt]
= {} &  \sum_{n=2}^N \left( \cos((n+1)x) - \cos(nx) \right) \\[8pt]
= {} &  \cos((N+1)x) - \cos(2x)
\end{align}
and for most values of $x$ this does not converge as $N\to\infty$.  Hence $\dfrac d{dx} \sum\limits_n\cdots$ is not in all cases equal to $\sum\limits_n\dfrac d{dx}\cdots$.

However, if a power series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \tag 1
$$
converges in an interval $(-R,R)$, then it can be validly differentiatied term-by-term in that interval.  This follows in part from the fact that the convergence of $(1)$ is uniform, not necessarily in the interval $(-R,R)$, but in every interval $(-R+a,R-a)$, no matter how small $a>0$ is.

(I might have considered attempting to include a proof in this answer, but you've already accepted another answer$\,\ldots$)

Comment: This is a bit understandable for me, but @Ian's answer was more well-rounded (I am not criticizing yours). But still, this may give me a pathway to the answer.

Comment: Wait a minute, this doesn't actually answer the question. I wasn't looking for if $$\frac{d}{dx} \sum a_n = \sum \frac{d}{dx} a_n$$, I was looking for the fact if it's mathematically sound to compute the summation of derivatives.